# Prevent ClickOnce To Download Application Data Files And Use Them Where They Are

Tags: file, clickonce

I Have a Program That Install Some Software on a Client Computer.
And Because Before Start It Needs .Net Framework 2, I Must Use Click Once Prerequisites To Install .Net Framework 2 First.
And Before Click Once Starts, it Just Copy All Of My Installation Files To Some Place Like : ' C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\0H6ZL...... '

They Are Big Installation Files And I Don't Want It To Copy Them There.
Is There Any Solution ?

Thanks For Your Time !

Comment: I just Doesnt Know That Minus Is For What. MayBe I Must Ask My Question This Way : I Just Dont Want My Program To Be Installed On Client System, I Want To Install Some Prerequisites Before Running My Program On Client Systems.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but let me make a stab at answering what I think you're asking.

The directory that you have cited in your question ("...\apps\2.0...") is the location of the ClickOnce cache, and it is not copying those files there before installing the .NET Framework, it is copying them there in order to install the ClickOnce application. This is where the application resides and runs from.

setup.exe is the bootstrapper. It checks for the prerequisites and installs them if necessary, and then kicks off the ClickOnce installation, which downloads the files to the aforementioned location. It has nothing to do with the installation of the prerequisites.

Comment: you're right, but i just dont want clickonce to copy those files, i just want it to install them from where they are !

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to do. The "installation files" for a Click Once deployment are the deployment files, and they have to be on the machine in order for the application to run. If you're talking about prerequisites, if you choose "install from vendor site" and you're talking about the .NET Framework, it uses the standard Microsoft install, and there's no way to install it differently other than providing the .NET setup files yourself.

Comment: If it's some other kind of files (data files, you say in your subject) that you don't want ClickOnce to download, then don't include them in your deployment. Put them on a website somewhere and use a link to access them from within the application.

Comment: thanks for your care. i just don't wanted the files to be copied to on the client machine and be installed from the CD i created from my deployment. although i created my setup program all by myself and now it's very better than ClickOnce ! thank you.